# Error while running 'mvn spring-boot:build-image'

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, maven

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.6.1:build-image (default-cli) on project my-spring-boot-app: Execution default-cli of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.6.1:build-image failed: Unable to find a single main class from the following candidates [com.example.MyApplication, com.example.Application]: [Help 1]
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.6.1:build-image (default-cli) on project my-spring-boot-app: Execution default-cli of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.6.1:build-image failed: Unable to find a single main class from the following candidates [com.example.MyApplication, com.example.Application]: [Help 1]
Using Java version 20 from BP_JVM_VERSION
No valid JRE available, providing matching JDK instead. Using a JDK at runtime has security implications.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  Can you [edit] your question to remove all of the images?  Is your question specific to the Docker build, or do you have the same issue just building your application jar file normally?

Comment: Normally building a JAR is working fine. I am facing an issue when trying to create the Docker image.